# How to find third point coordinates given variables

Tags: ruby, math, geometry, computational-geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I need a small algorithm in ruby to find x and y.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question.  But I would start with `((dInf - dSup)/2) / dX =  sin(ang)`, and solve for dX.

Comment: I think @AShelly means `= tan(ang)`.

Comment: Oops, yes. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
slope = Math.tan(ang)
x = (dInf - dSup)/(2 * slope)
y = x*slope + (dSub/2)
```

Y will be either positive or negative depending on which corner you want.

The reasoning for this is that the equation for the top slanted line is:
Y = Sin(ang) * X + (dSup/2)

So the question becomes "at what X do we get a Y = dInf/2"

Substituting Y: Sin(ang) * X + (dSup/2) = dInf/2

Rearranging:   X = (dInf - dSup) / 2 Sin(ang)

Comment: Use tangent for slope.